# Draw a transparent line using native win32 gdi

Tags: c#, winapi, gdi

I am drawing lines by using win32 gdi native apis. Now, I want to draw the line as transparent. I have set the alpha channel property in the color. However, setting the alpha channel in color is not drawing the line as transparent. I read about Alpha Blend Api but could not figure out the solution.

```
var hdc = g.GdiDeviceContext;
var srcHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

var clipRegion = CreateRectRgn(x, y, x + width, y + height);

SelectClipRgn(hdc, clipRegion);

var pen = CreatePen(PenStyle.Solid, LineWidth, (uint)ColorTranslator.ToWin32(colour));



if (pen != IntPtr.Zero)
{
     var oldPen = SelectObject(hdc, pen);
     Polyline(hdc, points, points.Length);
     SelectObject(hdc, oldPen);
     DeleteObject(pen);
}

SelectClipRgn(hdc, IntPtr.Zero);
AlphaBlend(hdc, x, y, width, height, srcHdc, x, y, width, height, new BlendFunction(0x00, 0, 0x7f, 0x00));
DeleteObject(clipRegion);
```

I am trying to draw the line as transparent.

Comment: *"it is not working"* is not a problem statement. Explain, what you expect to happen, as well as the observed behavior. It's also highly recommended that you use symbolic constants. As written, we have no idea, what properties your [BLENDFUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-_blendfunction) is supposed to have.

Comment: GDI harks from the olden days, it is a 24bpp api.  Bump up to GDI+, gdiplus.h header file.

Comment: @lInspectable I have modified the question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-_blendfunction are native win32 api and structures.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var srcHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
> ```

This creates a memory device context. This is the right first step. But the memory dc is not ready yet. It requires a memory bitmap as well.

> ```
> SelectObject(hdc, pen);
> Polyline(hdc, points, points.Length);
> ```

This will draw on windows device context. But we want to draw on memory device context, and then draw the memory on to `HDC` using `AlphaBlend`

See example below:

```
int w = 100;
int h = 100;

//create memory device context
var memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); 

//create bitmap
var hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);

//select bitmap in to memory device context
var holdbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

//begine drawing:
var hpen = CreatePen(0, 4, 255);
var holdpen = SelectObject(memdc, hpen);
Rectangle(memdc, 10, 10, 90, 90);

//draw memory device (memdc) context on to windows device context (hdc)
AlphaBlend(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, memdc, 0, 0, w, h, new BLENDFUNCTION(0, 0, 128, 0));

//clean up:
SelectObject(memdc, holdbmp);
SelectObject(memdc, holdpen);
DeleteObject(hbitmap);
DeleteObject(hpen);
DeleteDC(memdc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) . I followed the steps and first created the memory dc and assigned bitmap to it. After that, i did all the drawing on memdc and then blended it with hdc. However, still I am not getting the transparency (128 factor). Its completely opaque.

Comment: I tested this code and it draws a rectangle with the expected color. It will appear as a shade of red. There is no transparency. You can call it "semi-transparent". It is blending the color. Maybe you want `TransparentBlt`?