# GDI: How to draw a translucent line?

Tags: winapi, gdi

Let's say there is:

```
RoundRect(hdc, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 50, 50);
```

This is the pen:

```
CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 15, RGB(5, 61, 88));
```

How do I make the fill opaque and the stroke transparent (0-255 , whatever)?
In GDI (not in GDI+)

Answer (score 1):

GDI doesn't really support drawing a translucent line directly.

But you can draw your line to an off-screen bitmap the same size as the client area of the window where you want to draw, then use `AlphaBlend` to blend that bitmap into the destination window.

Comment: I tried to draw in this way, but I did not succeed. Would appreciate a working code.
Tried from this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52771600/3478155

Comment: You should probably ask *that* question then. Though, really, GDI simply doesn't support alpha transparency (with a few select exceptions). There's no way to draw an anti-aliased line, so that's something you would need to implement yourself anyway, in software. And by that time you might just want to go with GDI+ instead.

Comment: But i want to try via `AlphaBlend` first. Really impossible via GDI?

Comment: Who's going to supply the alpha values then? `RoundRect` won't do that for you. So now you're going to have to write your own ellipse rendering code with sub-pixel precision. That gets you both your alpha values and is really the only way to produce an ARGB image with pre-multiplied alpha. You're going to have to use pre-multiplied alpha, because that's the only rendering mode `AlphaBlend` supports.